Proving something is a $S_{3}$ submodule
Given that $S_{3}$ is the symmetric group on three elements ${\alpha,\beta,\gamma}$ and that $\mathbb{C}[\alpha,\beta,\gamma]$ is the permutation $G$-module with elements $a\alpha + b\beta + c\gamma$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$ and the action $g(a\alpha + b\beta + c\gamma) = ag\alpha + bg\beta + cg\gamma$ with $g \in S_{3}$, show that $<\beta-\alpha, \gamma-\beta> \leq \mathbb{C}[\alpha,\beta,\gamma]$ is a $S_{3}$-submodule and that
$$ <\beta-\alpha, \gamma-\beta> + <\alpha+\beta+\gamma> = \mathbb{C}[\alpha,\beta,\gamma]. $$
Additionally, show that it is irreducible.
Now, I know that $<\alpha+\beta+\gamma>$ is isomorphic to the trivial $S_{3}$-submodule and that $ <\beta-\alpha, \gamma-\beta>$ is two-dimensional, generated by elements
$$ a(\beta-\alpha) + b(\gamma-\beta) $$
for some $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$. I guess the idea here would be by showing that it is first closed under the action of the generators of $S_{3}$. But if I use for example (2 3), I should be getting
$$ a(2 3)(\beta - \alpha) + b(2 3)(\gamma - \beta) = a(\gamma - \alpha) + b(\gamma - \gamma),$$
which suggests an error on my part. Could someone perhaps clarify the situation for me? For the second task I should check that it is once again closed under the action of the generators, if I'm not wrong. For the third part I suppose I'd try to show it with some contradiction.
Thank you in advance

Any chance you could use symbols besides $1,2,3$ to make this infinitely more readable?

Right, apologies for that. Hopefully it's better now

So $\gamma-\gamma$ is $0$, right? can you think of how to get $\gamma-\alpha$ from $\gamma-\beta$ an $\beta-\alpha$?

Oh right, I can just sum them up. I got a little confused about working with the elements for some reason but we are in a vector space in the end.

Maybe I’m just confused, but shouldn’t $(2 , 3)(\gamma - \beta)$ be $\beta -\gamma$ instead of $\gamma - \gamma$?

@DavidGao Well, it should be a permutation that swaps $\beta$ for $\gamma$, if I'm not mistaken or if I have not misunderstood the way this works entirely.

@ThomasPetit It is a permutation, so by definition if it sends $\beta$ to $\gamma$, then it must send $\gamma$ to something other than itself, as otherwise it wouldn’t be injective (and permutations, being bijections, are in particular injective). The notation $(2 , 3)$ means the permutation that sends the second element to the third, and the third to the second. (More generally, $(a_1 , \cdots , a_n)$ is the cyclic permutation that sends $a_1$ to $a_2$, $a_2$ to $a_3$, and so on, and sends $a_n$ to $a_1$.)

Ooh yeah, my bad. It's been a while since I had to work with permutations. Thanks for that. So $a(2 3)(\beta - \alpha) + b(2 3)(\gamma - \beta)$ should give me $a(\gamma - \alpha) + b(\beta - \gamma)$?

@ThomasPetit That is correct.

Alright, so I managed to show that it is a two-dimensional submodule and it is irreducible, using a similar idea employed in this post - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2629022/show-that-a-submodule-is-isomorphic-to-the-two-dimensional-irreducible-subrepres
For the direct sum of modules, I have to show that every element on the right can be written as a sum of the elements on the left, correct?

@ThomasPetit To prove it’s a direct sum of two submodules, yes, you need to show every vector can be written as a sum of vectors in the two submodules and also the intersection of the two submodules is trivial.
